# The fastest way to create a file from a terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, files

What is the simplest way to create a file using a command-line? Usually I use:

```
touch filename
```

But is this the simplest/fastest way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will save you five keypresses relative to `touch filename`

```
>filename
```

but is not the equivalent of `touch` as it will truncate *filename* if it exists. The following does what you want

```
>>filename
```

but note that it is not equivalent to `touch` either, as it does not update *filename*'s modification timestamp.

Comment: Could also add `alias t='touch'` to your `.bashrc` :P