# How to add an option to create a new file with a specific extension in right click menu

Tags: nautilus, files, menu, filemanager

The title says all. I would like to have this option in right click menu on the desktop or in nautilus. I know that is possible, but I don't remember how to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to use `Templates` directory (or how is called in your language) from your home directory in this sense. Files from this folder will appear in the `New Document` menu. So, add the files with the extension what you want in this folder and you can create them after files with the same extension from the right click menu:

[image]

Moreover, if you add some predefined text in these files from `Templates` folder, the new files which you will create them from the right click menu will contain that text.

See also: [What is the "Templates" folder in the home directory for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/94734/147044)

Comment: +1 for showing a fast way to create blank empty files via the terminal.

Comment: @Jobin I know this from when I asked [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/348940/147044) :)

Comment: @Jobin be careful, if the file exist it will get truncated ;)