# Create templates for Gnome Commander

Tags: filemanager, templates

How do I make templates for Gnome Commander so that I can create files of my desired format from right click context menu?

By default via create button in the right click menu I can create only folder or plain text.I would like to be able to create Libre Office documents, presentations or tables from this menu.

Maybe someone can give suggestions for another twin-panel file manager that has this option? I have already used Krusader and it does work with templates, but seemed a bit heavyweight for my machine.

Comment: maybe duplicate of this: [How to add an option to create a new file with a specific extension in right click menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/385346/how-to-add-an-option-to-create-a-new-file-with-a-specific-extension-in-right-cli)

Comment: I already have templates in Nautilus and they work fine, but how can I transfer to Gnome Commander?

Comment: seems that i was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space Fm turned out to have these option being lightweight at the same time. I posted this an answer hoping it may be useful for someone.