# Creating a file in terminal

Tags: command-line, files

I am new to ubuntu and I am trying to create a file to fix a suspend problem I have with my system. I have found the answer here as follows:

> [Put attached script into dir /etc/pm/sleep.d e.g. with name fglrx-fix and make it executable (chmod u+x /etc/pm/sleep.d/fglrx-fix)](https://askubuntu.com/a/390828/)
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> #Script kills autofs when going into standby to eliminate issues with it
> case $1 in
>
> suspend)
> #suspending to RAM
>     chvt 1
>     echo "Going to sleep"
>     sleep 1
> ;;
> resume)
> #resume from suspend 
>     echo "try to resume"
>     sleep 1
>     chvt 7
> ;;       
> esac
> ```

I just cannot work out how to create the file in terminal, if someone could give a me a step by step instruction that would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The fastest way to create a file from a terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348940/the-fastest-way-to-create-a-file-from-a-terminal)

Comment: No, he wants a file with specific content.

Answer (score 2):

You'd most commonly use a command line editor like nano. You need to run it as root because of where you're trying to write:

```
sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/fglrx-fix
```

`nano` will open up allowing you to paste the code in. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit (press <kbd>Y</kbd> to confirm that you want to save it and <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm the filename).

Then (per the original instuctions) make it executable with:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/fglrx-fix
```

Comment: You could also use Text Editor, which is a little bit more user-friendly. To do that you would use the following command:

    `sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/fglrx-fix`

...And after you save and close it (when you close it in Text Editor it will return to your curson in the terminal), you would follow @Oli's instruction to make it executable.

Comment: I stayed away from graphical options because the problem at hand seems to be a graphical one. `nano` is universally available and isn't *that* hard to use :)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - I missed the OP's `flgrx`, which should have indicated a graphics/display issue to me. :p `vi` or `vim` works, too - but you are right, `nano` will work in the terminal no matter what.